# Implicit casting in templates and compiler coercion

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have this very simple wrapper template:

```
template<class T>
struct wrapper {
    inline operator T () {
        return v;
    }

    inline wrapper(T v):v(v) { }

    T v;
};
```

Trying to use it with any non-primitive type with (for example) comparison operator relying on the template having it defined doesn't look promising:

```
std::string t = "test";
assert(t == t);

typedef wrapper<std::string> string_wrapper;
assert(string_wrapper(t) == string_wrapper(t));
```

GCC 4.4.5 complains with this error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘wrapper<std::basic_string<char> >(std::basic_string<char>(((const std::basic_string<char>&)((const std::basic_string<char>*)(& t))))) == wrapper<std::basic_string<char> >(std::basic_string<char>(((const std::basic_string<char>&)((const std::basic_string<char>*)(& t)))))’
```

What is interesting is that GCC triple-casts the template then fails to use `operator ==` that was defined for `std::string`.

I don't think that implicit coercion is impossible, since if I change `std::string` to `int` or `double`, `bool` or anything primitive, GCC will choose the correct operator.

I do not want to define `operator ==` for the wrapper struct, because that operator is just an example, and I need `wrapper` to 'feel' just like the real type regarding operators.

Just in cast GCC misunderstands my syntax, if I create a wrapper and try to compare it to itself, GCC complains again (though without triple casting) that it cannot find a matching == operator:

```
typedef wrapper<std::string> string_wrapper;
string_wrapper tw(t);
assert(tw == tw);

error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘tw == tw’
```

Why can't GCC find and/or use `std::string operator == std::string` when `wrapper` provides the cast?

Comment: I tried that as well, it stills errors. I even tried making the entire wrapper struct const-correct - the error still occurs.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `wrapper` class?

Comment: In this case, nothing. However it's a simplified test case of a more complex problem primarily used to generate several other templates doing the same thing with extra functionality. I understand this example is really stupid and useless, just like any other example :)

Comment: If any of you question the existence of `wrapper`, I will happily supply a real world example.

Comment: As an aside, your use of the `inline` keyword here is redundant; member functions defined in the class definition are implicitly `inline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a GCC 4.5 bug. The code is valid, unlike what Fred Nurk says.

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45383

Comment: You have picked the wrong PR. It has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

That operator T is called a "conversion operator" or "conversion function" instead of a cast.  "Conversions" are implicit; casting is explicit.

The compiler can't find the operator== for std::string because the overload resolution rules don't allow that to happen.  More details about what you're really trying to do could help provide a solution.

Comment: Why when I change `std::string` to `int` it works? Also, in the same project, I got two separate classes that have casting operators to the same class, which do define an equality operator - and that works great. What is the difference here?

Comment: @LiraNuna: Built-in operators are considered independently of user-defined operators WRT to name lookup and context of the expression.  See §13.3.1.2p3 for details.

Comment: That is understood. How about the fact I have two distinct struct that define a casting operator to another class, which defines an operator ==, and GCC happily finds the correct way to cast both into it?

Comment: @LiraNuna: I tend to purposefully avoid implicit conversions.  I suspect there's a much better solution for what you really want to do that doesn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

The questioner has answered itself with some GCC PR, but which really does not answer his question.

The reason is like @Fred describes. Reducing it:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  operator T() { return T(); }
};

int main() {
  A<std::string>() == A<std::string>();
}
```

What can the compiler do? It could call `operator std::string()` on both operands and then do the comparison. But why should it do that call in the first place? It first needs to find an `operator==` that has two parameters of type `std::string`. Let's look at how its operator is defined

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator==(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
                const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs);
```

There we have it. It first needs to do template argument deduction, and the fact that `A` does not match `const basic_string<>` will make it so that this `operator==` is ignored. You are lucky that `operator==` is found anyway using ADL so that it does argument deduction in the first place (since `std::string` is a template argument of your type, it will consider namespace `std` by ADL and find this operator).

So we have no suitable `operator==` to call and therefor GCC is alright with rejecting your code for the reasons @Fred gave in a nutshell. In the end, trying to make a class behave like another type is deemed to failure.